# Как сделать чтобы slick-slider начинался со второго элемента?

Tags: javascript, slick.js

Как сделать чтобы slick-slider начинался со второго элемента?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать `initialSlide` для этого. Обратите внимание, что первый слайд имеет номер 0, поэтому, если вы хотите, чтобы слайдер начинался со второго слайда, используйте `initialSlide: 1`.

[Slick Carousel - Set first slide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41526659/slick-carousel-set-first-slide)